# Response is url encoded when using Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2, httpurlconnection, urlencode

When I use regular `HttpURLConnection` and `BufferedReader` I am getting just plain unicode text in resulting `String`:

```kotlin
val url = URL(urlStr)
val response = StringBuilder()
val con: HttpURLConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0")
val bufferedReader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(con.inputStream))
var inputLine: String?
while (bufferedReader.readLine().also { inputLine = it } != null) {
    response.append(inputLine)
}
bufferedReader.close()

return response.toString()
```

I try to migrate this request to `Retrofit` using `ScalarsConverterFactory` and getting just String from my Retrofit service method. The issue with this solution is that now the result string from Retrofit is url-encoded (like `"%C2 %96"`):

```
  @Headers("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0")
    @GET("single?client=gtx&dt=t")
    suspend fun getTranslation(
        @Query("sl") sourceLanguage: String,
        @Query("tl") targetLanguage: String,
        @Query("q") text: String,
    ): String
```

I tried to use `URLDecoder` but am geting `URLDecoder: Illegal hex characters in escape (%) pattern` error.

1. Why Retrofit returns url-encoded string?
2. How should I properly decode this string to avoid the error?
3. How could I change this behaviour and just get plain (not encoded) string, like with `HttpURLConnection` ?

Answer (score 0):

Look I've encountered this error before but I found the reason very trivial and the solution is when you make a request it gives you the response as an image and you decode the image and the response seems to you as it is encrypted but this thing is not in your mind and the response seems to be encrypted because it returns the binary file.
All you have to do is use the URL directly with the parameter that you need , that's it

Comment: In my case the response is just text (json). As I mentioned in my question, when I use plain `HttpURLConnection` everything works fine. So I assume the issue is somehow connected to the `Retrofit` or `Okio`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).